# How to access xbian partition?

Tags: sd-card, kodi, mount, xbian

I've installed xbian on RPi.

I want to edit the files in my SD card using my computer, Ubuntu 14.04.

However, when I insert the SD card, the Ubuntu cannot mount the Xbian partition, and gives the following error:

[image: Error: Unable to mount xbian partition]

and when I type `dmesg | tail`  , it gives the following:

[image: Error Messages]

Now what should I do to access the contents of xbian partition on SD card!?

Answer (score 1):

You could try booting the pi in [safe mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=12007), although if the file system is corrupt that might not be much help. You can ssh into it if it gets a full but in, but that seems unlikely if nothing is coming up on the screen at all. There is no default IP, but you can check the connected computers in your router settings usually to see the pi's address.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron-W for your help. Unfortunately, it seems that SSH is not possible at the moment. I should find a way to directly access the contents of SD card.